# Is it possible to create OSM-like rendering rules for Maperitive?

Tags: openstreetmap, maperitive

I have been trying to replicate the style of OSM in Maperitive. However, there are parts that do not render with the rendering rules I have so far (I tried creating it by tweaking the default rendering rules).

What I need are rendering rules that look like OpenStreetMap but without the text. Is there somewhere I can find that, or do anybody here have any advice on how I can make one? To be a tad more specific, I need to create maps that looks like the Standard map on OpenStreetMap.org. However, I need those to be without text labels.

Of course, this assumes that it is possible to replicate the OSM Standard map in Maperitive; The default rendering rules in Maperitive seems to, in my opinion fail, since parts of the map do not even seem to render; So, certain parks just return grey.

So, is it possible to render OSM-like map in Maperitive?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you looked at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:WeekThor/OSM-carto_rule/Version_1.0_(31.03.2020) which tries to replicate the osm-carto style for Maperitive? You would still have to work on excluding text to render, but maybe the ruleset by WeekThor is a good starting/comparing point.